# Why doesnt a default value affect the table in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Im trying to update my tables and add new column, to this column should be a default Integer value, I tried to use default and also default_server as recommend here: [Why isn't sqlalchemy's default column value working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348801/why-isnt-sqlalchemys-default-column-value-working)
 but the value of this field stay null, It is possible to set Integer default value?

```
col = Column(field_name, data_type, default=0)
column_name = column.compile(dialect=engine.dialect)
column_type = column.type.compile(engine.dialect)
engine.execute('ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s %s' % (table_name, column_name, column_type))
```

Comment: Btw please tag questions using raw SQL with the DBMS you're using, since some statements can differ between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your manual `ALTER TABLE` statement *does not add the default* and leaves the column nullable; having `server_default` on the `Column` object has no effect. If you want a default, add it:

```
engine.execute('ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s %s DEFAULT 0' % (table_name, column_name, column_type))
```

I'd highly recommend using [alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) for database migrations.

Comment: While I appreciate the thanks, have a look at ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)